# Is it a bad idea to drill a hole through this door frame to pass wires?

Tags: doors, closet

I want to pass my ethernet, speaker and sub wires into my newly built media/bar cabinet, but I hate having to pass them under the door, so I'd like to drill a hole as shown by the green circle in the image.

[image]

Bad idea?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea (see answer below). Based on your picture, it's a older house so there is likely a 4" stud that you'll need to drill through so be ready for that and be ready for nails.

Comment: It doesn't deserve a new answer because the other ones are perfect in their own right. Just an addition: use a larger tool to make the hole, making sure that all current and future plugs can pass through, not just the wires. Then simply cover the hole with what is known as a cable (desk) grommet, something like this: http://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8zAwbXnvEXKJk43KUq6xdxpXa4.jpg

Comment: You're not going to run mains power through this, are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bad idea what so ever. However, let me clarify on the posted answer... A hole saw can be used to cut clean perfect holes, but are limited in cut depth. You'll most likely need to use the hole saw on both sides of the jamb.

A hole hog, as another commenter mentioned, is also known as an auger bit. It has a pointed threaded tip that will pull the bit thru whatever material you're trying to drill thru until the tip can't pull anymore. From there you'll need a little extra force to get the bit to finish it's cut.

Both are feasible tools for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Micro-note... the auger bit is likely to produce a bunch of tearout on the far side. Drill until the threaded point just emerges, then drill the remainder from that side.

Comment: A 3/8" bit extender will put a holesaw through anything; it's just a pita.

Comment: If you get a long enough bit extender (like 18") you can put the hole inline with the track and go straight thru (butchering a hole from both sides, using whatever bits - 'butchered' because it will be at a slight angle and so needs be a little larger).

Comment: A bit extender won't change the depth of the hole saw bit. If the hole saw bit depth is 2", then you can only cut 2" deep before you have to remove the plug from the bit to cut further...

Comment: Would using a spade bit do the trick as well?

Comment: @jwilcox09 Yes, a spade aka. paddle bit will work as well. I didn't mention that as they have a tendency to twist. From my experience anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a hole cutter instead of drilling a hole so the hole can be future proofed if you want to pass more wires someday.

Comment: Those both sound like drilling a hole to pass wires. Whats the difference between them?

Comment: A hole cutter can make a bigger hole then a big gauged drill. In the past I have found it hard to turn a small hole into a bigger hole with a hole cutter because they're is nothing in the center for the drill bit to drill into.

Comment: Never heard of it referred to as a hole cutter before. I'm used to hole saw for creating a very clean hole with a plug as a result and hole hog which cuts through very quickly, shredding everything in it's path, both which come in larger diameters than normal drill bits.

Comment: Hole saw would be brutal to get through there, use an auger as @BillWickel suggests

Comment: "hole saw" would be the normal name for a sawblade bent into a cylinder.  "hole cutter" would be a something similar to a lathe cutter tool on a radial post something like a really big caliper that can be adjusted.  OP probably doesn't have room for anything wide, and the drill's body will probably be the limiting factor, getting it pressed up against the adjacent wall while keeping the holesaw straight.

Comment: Are you guys kidding? Let's drill a big hole in a wall that may be a load bearing wall, that's what I hear. Even a small hole with a drill bit could cause disaster depending what is behind this wall. Data may be ok but other than that just a 3/8" spade bit if there is no plumbing wiring and load bearing walls would work.

Comment: @EdBeal where are you seeing a load bearing wall? The OP seems to be asking about drilling through a door jamb which certainly shouldn't be load bearing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I made that comment as it could be, just a dumb idea to dri'll holes as large as the comments suggest, any stud that had a huge hole could have issues

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but I would actually go through the wall between the molding and the corner.  Measure things on the side from the picture, transpose the hole location into the other room and drill from the other room. 3/4" auger or installer bit should fit fine.     That's just me.

Drilling the frame will end up being like 5" of solid wood counting the doubled stud and the molding, drilling into that space will be just wall material/hollow cavity/wall material. It will also be less likely to cause issues in the future.  Need larger hole? Elongate with a jab saw, and use those plastic cable hiders to cover the hole.